# Why do we get "so did they do" for the commandment of expelling tamei people in Parashat Naso?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, tzaraas-negaim, parshat-nasso

Parashat Naso, in [Numbers 5:1-3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9933#v1), presents a commandment to "send from the camp" anyone who is *[tamei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumah)* due to either *[tzara'at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzaraath)* or a *[zav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zav)*-type discharage. After that, we have [Verse 4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9933#v4), affirming that the Israelites did as commanded:

> וַיַּעֲשׂוּ כֵן בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וַיְשַׁלְּחוּ אוֹתָם אֶל מִחוּץ לַמַּחֲנֶה כַּאֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר יְהוָֹה אֶל משֶׁה כֵּן עָשׂוּ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל
>
> The children of Israel did so: they sent them outside the camp; as the Lord had spoken to Moses, so did the children of Israel do.

It seems to me that this commandment was meant to apply in perpetuity and was not a one-time expulsion. If so, it seems atypical that the Torah would record the fact that it was adhered to the first time. (One other example that comes to mind was a record in [Numbers 9:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9937#v5) that the Israelites performed the first *[Korban Pesach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korban_Pesach)* after the Exodus, but I can see various reasons for that, including that it was leading into the [Pesach Sheini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesach_Sheini) story.)

- Am I right that this sort of "and so they did" is atypical for commandments meant to apply in perpetuity?
- If so, why did this commandment, in particular, get such a record?

Comment: Perhaps because only now (re the rest of the parsha) did the mishkan/mikdash start functioning and everyone had to actually be kicked out.

Comment: [Exodus 12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm) 28, 35, 50

Comment: @DoubleAA The commandments in Exodus 12 were explicitly one-timers and part of the Exodus story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second posuk says "צַו אֶת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל" - Command the Children of Israel, and Rashi explains in his [commentary on Leviticus 6:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9907#showrashi=true&v=2) that whenever the Torah writes צו it means that the command has to be carried out immediately and for all generations.

> אין צו אלא לשון זרוז מיד ולדורות. אמר ר' שמעון ביותר צריך הכתוב לזרז במקום שיש בו חסרון כיס:‏
>
> The expression צַו always denotes urging [to promptly and meticulously fulfill a particular commandment] for the present and also for future generations. Rabbi Simeon taught: Scripture especially needs to urge [people to fulfill commandments,] where monetary loss is involved.

Therefore, verse 4 tells us that they carried out the "immediate" part of the command.